# Quickest way to get the sum of the length of a list of vectors

Tags: summation, vectors

sadly I'm "just" a programmer, so maybe this website is the best point for asking for advanced math "magic" :)

I'm given a list of 3d-points and my task would be to get the complete length of the path.

So my current solution is to just $\| \mathbf{p1-p0} \| + \| \mathbf{p2-p1} \| + \| \mathbf{p3-p2} \| + ...$

That is creating the first vector from the first two points, getting its length...

The problem here is that I'm always doing a square root each time I calculate the magnitude of a vector.

Is there a way I can reduce the number of square roots i have to do?
At the moment I have to use n-1 square roots (where n is the number of points).

(and for all non-programmers: doing a square root is one of the slower functions, so it should definitely be avoided!)

Comment: I don't see any way to reduce the number of square roots, but you may find some useful information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: Here is another reference on the fast inverse square root: http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf

Comment: @yhhuang, that trick was useful when srqt was an expensive operation, not done in hardware. Today doing a sqrt is cheaper than accessing data in memory.